# Where is the Visual Studio 2015 NuGet Client manager?

Tags: nuget, nugetgallery

I uninstalled the nuget package manager in an attempt to fix a bug.  When I went to reinstall it I can't find it in the gallery.  Anyone know where it's located?

The link from here is dead :(

http://docs.nuget.org/consume/installing-nuget

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d345edc-2e2d-4a9c-b73b-d53956dc458d

Comment: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c?SRC=Home
There it is

Comment: @szoszk That's for 2013/10.  For Visual studio 2015 it was called "NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2015"

Comment: Oh, OK I'm trying to start visual Studio to check it but it somehow loads very long. Already waiting for 5 min.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently they moved it to github:

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/releases/tag/3.1.1

Not sure why it went missing from the extensions gallery though.

Comment: The NuGet Package Manager 2015 page in the extensions gallery not being available has been fixed now.